# How to calculate unconditional correlation coefficient?

Tags: probability

Let X be a Bernoulli random variable with success parameter p, where p is uniformly distributed over the interval (0,1). Suppose p is chosen, then two independent observations of X (call them X_1 and X_2) are made. What is the unconditional correlation coefficient between X_1 and X_2?

Comment: You need more than one data point for a correlation. Are $X_0, X_1$ vectors with a fixed $p$? Or is this process of picking a random $p$ repeated per trial?

Comment: Yes, X_1 and X_2 are equal to 1 or 0 with independent probability of a fixed p. So I'm not sure how to calculate an unconditional correlation coefficient. If I've fixed p, then I'm calculating a conditional correlation coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1}X_{2}\mid P=p\right)=p^{2}$ and $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1}\mid P=p\right)=p=\mathbb{E}\left(X_{2}\mid P=p\right)$

Leading to $\mathbb{E}X_{1}X_{2}=\mathbb{E}P^{2}$ and $\mathbb{E}X_{1}=\mathbb{E}P=\mathbb{E}X_{2}$

So $\text{Covar}X_{1}X_{2}=\mathbb{E}X_{1}X_{2}-\mathbb{E}X_{1}\mathbb{E}X_{2}=\mathbb{E}P^{2}-\left(\mathbb{E}P\right)^{2}=\text{Var}P=\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: Thanks so much! Just to confirm the second line. To get from $E(X_1X_2 | P=p)$ to $E(X_1X_2)$, you did $\int_0^1 E(X_1X_2 | P = p) P_P(p) dp = \int_0^1 p^2 dp = EP^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I did it like that.